# diagonalization of quadratic form over R

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, diagonalization, quadratic-forms, bilinear-form

I have the quadratic form

$$q\left(x_1,\:x_2,\:x_3,x_4\right)=2x_1x_4-6x_2x_3$$

$q:\:R^4-R^4$

I need to :

1. express it as a sum of quadrants (quadratic terms)
2. find a base B of $R^4$ in which q is diagonal.
3. find sub-space $U$ of $R^4$ of maximal dimension, that $\forall \ \ 0 \neq x\in U,\:q\left(u\right)>0 $

I see that $$\left[q\right]_E=\begin{pmatrix}0&0&0&1\\ 0&0&-3&0\\ 0&-3&0&0\\ 1&0&0&0\end{pmatrix}$$

Is it diagnolizable or am I wrong in its representation ?
Can I express it as sum of quadratic elements at all ?
Ho do I approach to that last question ?

I tried the method, which says "do raw and col elementary operations on $[q]_E$ to get a diagonal matrix, and then repeat the columns operations them on the I matrix and i supposed to get P, but some why I couldn't diagonilize $[q]_E$, I mean technically/algebraic. (maybe I missed it somehow dk)"

Comment: If "quadrants" means "quadratic terms", then it is enough to complete the square of some binomials

Comment: by the way, every symmetric matrix is diagonalizable thanks to the spectral theorem

Answer (score 1):

$$4ab=(a+b)^2-(a-b)^2$$

Hence $$2x_1x_4-6x_2x_3=\tfrac{1}{2}(x_1+x_4)^2-\tfrac{1}{2}(x_1-x_4)^2-\tfrac{3}{2}(x_2+x_3)^2+\tfrac{3}{2}(x_2-x_3)^2$$

Comment: So the base is $\begin{pmatrix}1\\ 0\\ 0\\ 1\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}1\\ \:0\\ \:0\\ -1\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}0\\ 1\\ 1\\ 0\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}0\\ \:1\\ \:-1\\ \:0\end{pmatrix}$ and q in this base is $\begin{pmatrix}\frac{1}{2}&0&0&0\\ 0&-\frac{1}{2}&0&0\\ 0&0&-\frac{3}{2}&0\\ 0&0&0&\frac{3}{2}\end{pmatrix}$ ?

and the subspace is whole $R^4$ because it's rank is 4 ?